# Is this enough to prevent against header injection and other vulnerabilities ?

Tags: python, security, python-2.7, flask, flask-wtforms

I am writing a contact form using Flask .

```
@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
    form = ContactForm()
    title = u"Contact us"

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate() == False:
            flash (u'All fields are required' )
            return render_template('contact.html', form=form, title=title)
        else:            
            msg = Message(u"[Appname]"+ form.subject.data,
                  sender=form.email.data,
                  recipients=["MyEmail@gmail.com"])
            msg.body = form.message.data
            mail.send(msg)
            return render_template('contact.html', success=True)

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('contact.html', form=form, title=title)
```

And the contact class is :

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, BooleanField, TextAreaField, SubmitField, validators, ValidationError
class ContactForm(Form):
    name = TextField("Name",  [validators.Required("Name ")])
    email = TextField("Email",  [validators.Required("Email "), validators.Email("Email ")])
    subject = TextField("subject",  [validators.Required("Subject ")])
    message = TextAreaField("Message",  [validators.Required("Message ")])
    submit = SubmitField("Send")
```

Is that code enough to prevent against email header injection, xss and code execution ? 
Does Flask provide security checks before executing code ?

PS : I know that a captcha is needed here, but my question is not about spam.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking for someone to review a piece of code that is already functional. Questions such as this are better suited at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Yes, maybe. But this is a kind of "standard" code to write a contact form in Flask. Exactly, I am not asking about the code iteself but about the security behind a form code written in Flask.

Comment: This is sort of a gray area, and so I'm revoking my close vote. However, keep in mind that what you've provided is not "standard" code; it is code that you wrote (albeit code that looks SIMILAR to code you've seen in tutorials). Therefore, the answer to the question "is this code safe from X" can be different from the answer to the question "does Flask/Flask-WTF/Flask-EMail protect you from injection/code execution/etc".

Comment: This is as secure as the `Message` class you didn't provided is secure. Provide it and we'll be able to tell.